# Fishpig Disqus Comments Not Showing Up

Tags: magento, disqus, fishpig

I have recently installed the latest version of fishpig Wordpress Integration on my Magento and have bought the fishpig disqus extension to go along with my wordpress blog. 
The disqus comments do not seem to show up, do I have to create a disqus.phtml template in order to implement these comments and override the other comments page in the wordpress templates, or should it just do so automatically? If the latter, why might it not be doing so?

(note: I also do not have a wordpress.xml file in my custom theme, but I do have some custom templates that are expounded in my local.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to install the free Disqus plugin in your WordPress Admin, setup a Disqus account and configure everything. Once this has been configured in Disqus and the WordPress Admin, the FishPig extension will read this data and display the Disqus comments automatically.